# How to anonymize certain fields using Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, datamapper

We have a set of entities that contains data fields that needs to be anonymized to certain users. We have a product database, but the true name of the product should only be visible to certain users. Other users should just see the "anonymous" version of the product name (the anonymous name is stored in another field in the product table)

How can I accommodate this using Entity Framework in an easy matter. We have a mapper framework in place and a service layer and our first approach was to map the final results for all methods that returned a list of products, but we're kind of loosing the navigational properties and we would like to avoid to replicate the complete EF-structure as DTOs.

Is there a simple way of injecting user-based data replacement in EF?

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would use an Abstraction layer that did this. Eg Respository Pattern.

```
public virtual TPoco Get(Expression<Func<TPoco, bool>> predicate) {
 //This routine would execute the normal find or first as you like...eg
 var resultEntity = Context.Set<TPoco>().FirstOrDefault(predicate);
 // but before returning.
 var anonResult  = Blender<poco>(TPoco resultEntity); // this does the anon massaging 
 return AnonResult;
}
```